# find input type from name

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to get the type of the input from the name? For instance: for `<input type="text" name="abc" />` I want to know whether it is input, textarea or select. So, is it possible to find the type of input from name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var eltype = $('*[name="abc"]').prop('tagName');
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/UDcYD/

**EDIT**

as @Wesley Murch stated the `tagName` property returns a uppercase string, if you need it lower case just do something like that:

```
var eltype = $('[name="abc"]').prop('tagName').toLowerCase();
```

@Wesley Murch is right again saying that `*` in not neccessary infact `[name="abc"]` is enough to select element with name `abc`

**EDIT2**

`tagName` is a property of the jQuery object you selected with `[name="abc"]` which represents its tag name. In your question you called it type but actually the right name is tag name.

**EDIT3**

If you are using a jQuery version < 1.6 you have to use `attr` instead of `prop` as prop function has been introduced with jQuery 1.6

```
var eltype = $('[name="abc"]').attr('tagName').toLowerCase();
```

anyway my advise is to upgrade jQuery if you do no have too much code relying on the old jQuery you have

Comment: Note that this will often (always?) return an uppercase tag name, so make sure you keep that in mind if doing a comparison to a string, there will be trouble using something like `if (eltype === 'input')`. (Also the `*` is not necessary)

Comment: Whether it's uppercase or lowercase depends on the browser and the doctype, so you should always normalise it with `toUpper/LowerCase`.

Comment: yeah it seems to work in jsfiddle but I am getting this error "TypeError: $("*[name=\"abc\"]").prop is not a function"

Comment: which jQuery verion are you using? if it is prior 1.6 you should use `attr` instead of `prop`

Answer (score 0):

For retrieving input type:

```
$('*[name="abc"]').attr('type');
```

For retrieving tag name:

```
$('*[name="abc"] :eq(0)').tagName;
```

Comment: This won't get the element type, just the `type` attribute. "I want to know whether it is input, textarea or select."

Comment: yeah this is giving "select-one" for select

Comment: The tagName is not displayed :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
$element = $('*[name="target"]');
$result = $('#result');
if ($element.prop('tagName') == 'INPUT') {
    $result.text($element.attr('type'));
}
else {
    console.log('foo');
    $result.text($element.prop('tagName').toLowerCase());
}
```

This should work for both inputs and `<select>`s etc.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/RfXyM/)**